# How to add a post after / before row in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have already some posts in database table but i want to add a new record after or before a existing row. i can't have (int) column and i don't want (int) column. 
i have table like:

```
-------------------------------
|  Date  |  Time  | Person_No |
-------------------------------
|07-06-15|  09:30 |     12    |  // i want to add a new record after this row, like time: 10:00 
-------------------------------
|07-06-15|  10:30 |     12    |
-------------------------------
|07-06-15|  11:00 |     12    |
-------------------------------
```

please tell me how is possible to add a new record after Date: 07-06-15 time : 09:30 p_no : 12
.....

Comment: Note that dates/times adhere to a specific format/data type in SQL. This is not it. Also, they're generally best stored as a single entity. Fix that, and then get back to us - once you've figured out what BEFORE and AFTER might mean in the context of an unordered set!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting data into tables is usualy based on the way you sort it, so for example in your case you'd just insert the row and then use `ORDER BY DATE [ASCENDING|DESCENDING]` (use ascending or descending order based on how you want it to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as insert between rows. Just insert your value.

However, when you select from your database you just use `ORDER BY`

Example:

```
SELECT date, time, Person_No FROM tbl_name
ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
```